# Half riddle and half rebus

Tags: riddle, rebus

I am a string ?????.
I consist of five symbols.
If you plug me into the following Rebus puzzles, I will make a lot of sense.

Rebus 1:

```
 ????? AZ
```

Rebus 2:

```
 ????? vs 1
```

Rebus 3:

```
 ?????
 FAVORITE
```

What am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> 13579

The three rebus puzzles become

> 13579 AZ = **"ODDS and ends"**

and

> 13579 vs 1 = **"The ODDS are against one"**

and

> 13579 on FAVORITE = **"ODDS-on favorite"**